# Bootstrap timepicker does not close when clicked outside the white area

Tags: bootstrap-4, fancybox, timepicker, fancybox-3

When I try to open a timepicker in Fancybox 3 version it works perfectly. But when I click outside the timepicker field on any empty area within fancybox the timepicker doesn't closes.

However If I click on any other field other than the time picker it closes. It is just a white area where it doesn't close at all.

Help!

Comment: This will be fixed in the upcoming release, you can preview it here - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBwbeV

Comment: Till then is there any hack which we can use to get rid of this issue in current release? cannot put my client on hold by then.

Comment: Sorry, there is no "hack". You can grab source code from that codepen demo un use that while next version is released.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine after updating to the latest version.